# Pass a PHP array to a JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to get a PHP array variable into a JavaScript variable.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              function drawChart(row,day,week,month,date)
              {
                  // Some code...
              }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            for($counter = 0; $counter<count($au); $counter++)
            {
                switch($au[$counter]->id)
                {
                    case pageID.'/insights/page_active_users/day':
                        $day[] = $au[$counter]->value;
                    break;
                    case pageID.'/insights/page_active_users/week':
                        $week[] = $au[$counter]->value;
                    break;
                    case pageID.'/insights/page_active_users/month':
                        $month[] = $au[$counter]->value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        ?>
        <script>
            drawChart(600/50, '<?php echo $day; ?>', '<?php echo $week; ?>', '<?php echo $month; ?>', '<?php echo createDatesArray(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m',strtotime('-1 day')), date('Y',strtotime('-1 day')))); ?>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't get value of the PHP array.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the following example you have an PHP array, then firstly create a JavaScript array by a PHP array:

```
<script type="javascript">
    day = new Array(<?php echo implode(',', $day); ?>);
    week = new Array(<?php echo implode(',',$week); ?>);
    month = new Array(<?php echo implode(',',$month); ?>);

    <!--  Then pass it to the JavaScript function:   -->

    drawChart(<?php echo count($day); ?>, day, week, month);
</script>
```

Comment: what's the point of using Ajax when using PHP, when you can just inject PHP directly into the script?

Comment: You can't execute php code on button click without using ajax

Answer (score 215):

Use  [JSON](http://www.json.org/example.html).

In the following example `$php_variable` can be any PHP variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = <?php echo json_encode($php_variable); ?>;
</script>
```

In your code, you could use like the following:

```
drawChart(600/50, <?php echo json_encode($day); ?>, ...)
```

In cases where you need to parse out an object from JSON-string (like in an AJAX request), the safe way is to use `JSON.parse(..)` like the below:

```
var s = "<JSON-String>";
var obj = JSON.parse(s);
```

Comment: What would be the disadvantage of simply writing `var obj = <?php echo json_encode($php_variable); ?>;`? Won't PHP encode the JSON object securely in a way that it's parsable by the script?

Comment: Yes, that is *the* way. But my intention was to put across `JSON.parse()` as one safe way to parse from string. Thanks for pointing, I will edit my post.

Comment: var data = <?php echo json_encode($registos); ?>; returns the error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: i am getting this error, too (Unexpected token <)

Comment: @RemusRigo & Nuno: Just a guess, are you opening PHP tags within PHP tags? In any case, please post a new question.

Comment: You can use json then convert it back into an array using:
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k] });

Comment: First semicolon is unnecessary, this also works: `var obj = <?php echo json_encode($php_variable) ?>;`

Answer (score 83):

You can pass PHP arrays to JavaScript using `json_encode` PHP function.

```
<?php
    $phpArray = array(
        0 => "Mon", 
        1 => "Tue", 
        2 => "Wed", 
        3 => "Thu",
        4 => "Fri", 
        5 => "Sat",
        6 => "Sun",
    )
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;

    for(var i=0; i<jArray.length; i++){
        alert(jArray[i]);
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: can you help?  `permission[1]=0` php array becomes object like this `"permission":{"1":["0"]}`, while `permission[0]=0` remains Array.

Comment: hey @shyammakwana.me you might have made a nested array, check print_r($array) before json_encode() and see if the array formed is like same as above then it will work fine.

Comment: Hi @Tarun thanks for reply, yes my array is like `$p[1][0] = 0 ;` and it gives object in my JS, it's nested. how to overcome this?

Comment: This should be the most upvoted, since this is what OP is asking for

Answer (score 15):

Data transfer between two platform requires a common data format. JSON is a common global format to send cross platform data.

```
drawChart(600/50, JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($day); ?>'), JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($week); ?>'), JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($month); ?>'), JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(createDatesArray(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m',strtotime('-1 day')), date('Y',strtotime('-1 day'))))); ?>'))
```

This is the answer to your question. The answer may look very complex. You can see a simple example describing the communication between server side and client side [here](http://www.htmlexplorer.com/2014/05/send-or-communicate-data-structures.html)

```
$employee = array(
 "employee_id" => 10011,
   "Name" => "Nathan",
   "Skills" =>
    array(
           "analyzing",
           "documentation" =>
            array(
              "desktop",
                "mobile"
             )
        )
);
```

Conversion to JSON format is required to send the data back to client application ie, JavaScript. PHP has a built in function json_encode(), which can convert any data to JSON format. The output of the json_encode function will be a string like this.

```
{
    "employee_id": 10011,
    "Name": "Nathan",
    "Skills": {
        "0": "analyzing",
        "documentation": [
            "desktop",
            "mobile"
        ]
    }
}
```

On the client side, success function will get the JSON string. Javascript also have JSON parsing function JSON.parse() which can convert the string back to JSON object.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        url: "employee.php",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            employee_id: 10011
        },
        success: function (jsonString) {
            var employeeData = JSON.parse(jsonString); // employeeData variable contains employee array.
    });
```

Comment: too bad the "here" link is now dead.