# Including JavaScript in PHP function Error

Tags: php, javascript

I had a weird problem here. Please check the code below. I do not understand how this code below is created by somehow part of it is working, considering mixture of php variables and javascript variables.

First, let us see what the alert() outputs (take note that $lat and $lng is different from the array $vlat):

1. In Line 8 of the code below, alert(eventlocation) properly displays the coordinates of the GoogleMap latlng (so the implementation is correct)
2. In Line 13, alert(s) was able to display incrementing values (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,..) based on the for loop in the previous line so it is also correct.
3. In Line 14, alert($vlat[0]) was able to display the latitude of the first element of that array (declared before this set of codes) so it is also correct
4. In Line 15, alert($vlat[1]) was able to display the latitude of the second element of that array so it is also correct
5. But in Line 16, alert($vlat[s]) displayed undefined.

Can anyone explain that? Thanks

```
    echo "<script src= 'http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAA2jrOUq9ti9oUIF0sJ8it1RTNr3PHi_gURF0qglVLyOcNVSrAsRRu2C3WQApcfD0eh9NLdzf9My0b9w' type='text/javascript'> </script>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    function getabc(){
        var eventlocation;
        var volunteerlocation;
        var s;
        eventlocation = new GLatLng($lat, $lng);
        //alert(eventlocation);
        var volunteerDist = new Array();
        s = $ctr;
        var tvid = new Array();
        for(s=0;s<$numrows;s++){
            //alert(s);
            //alert($vlat[0]);
            //alert($vlat[1]);
            //alert($vlat[s]);
        }
    }
    a = getabc();     < /script>";
```

Comment: $ctr is declared before this and it is initially set to 0 (zero)

Comment: what is `$vlat` set to? it looks like that variable doesn't contain anything at index s

Comment: @jlb $ctr is initially set to zero, s is set to variable $ctr mainly because for some reasons, using $ctr in the for loop gives an error

Comment: I believe the issue is you're accessing the PHP array `$vlat` (on the server side) with an index value only later defined in the JS part (on the client side).

Comment: Try `print_r($vlat)` before your echo statement to see what that variable contains.

Comment: @Jeff print_r($vlat) return all the values of the array

Comment: @Stijn but how can I can alert the values of the $vlat if i set [0] or [1] into it but if s, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert($vlat[0]);
alert($vlat[1]);
alert($vlat[s]);
```

`$vlat[0]`, `$vlat[1]` and `$vlat[s]` are parsed on the server before they is sent to the client. The first two can be resolved, but PHP does not know what `s` is, since `s` is only defined once the client side is reached.

*Edit from chat discussion*

```
$json = json_encode($vlat);

echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
   function test(){
       var obj = JSON.parse('$json');
       alert(obj);
   }
   < /script>";
```

Comment: You can serialise the PHP array to JSON, so it can be accessed by the JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4885796/247702

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($vlat); ?>'); does not work.. there is an error

Comment: it just does not show anything.. meaning there is an error.. the process stops after this line is called

Comment: When you look at the source of the rendered page, what are you seeing in place of `__THIS__` in `var obj = JSON.parse('__THIS__');`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8909/discussion-between-stijn-and-brandon-young)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `s` that you are using to index the PHP array `vlat` is a variable that you declared in JavaScript. You cannot use it to index a PHP array.

What your code tries to do is to have PHP access a JavaScript variable, which it cannot. You can have PHP echo JavaScript, yes, but it doesn't work both ways.

Comment: so what do you suggest i should do?

Comment: I'd suggest passing in $vlat as an object into javascript, and looping through it in pure JS rather than trying to access the PHP variable in your JS loop. Something like `var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($vlat);?>; ` might work.

Comment: var obj = <?php echo json_encode($vlat);?>;
alert(obj);

there is an error so alert() does not run;