# passing a php array to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php that echos html.  Inside one of these echos I have a button that calls a javascript function.  Inside of this call I pass a php variable.  However when I see what the value of one of the elements is inside of the javascript I get undefined.

Any ideas?

Javascript

```
function addrow(innerid, teams){


    alert(teams[1]);}
```

Here is how I pass it, this is all inside of an echo

```
<input type = "button" id = '.$buttonid.'  value = "Agregar" onclick = "addrow(\'' . $leaguesarray[$numofleagues] . '\','.$teamsarray.')
```

So I call addrow(with a league value, and I also pass the array teamsarray from php

I've decided to try something else but I'm not getting it to work correctly.

Any suggestions?

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';


for ($size = 0; $size < sizeof($teamsarray);$size++){

    echo "var teamsarray[".$size."] = ".$teamsarray[$size].";\n";


    }

echo 'function addrow(innerid, size){


for (var i = 0;i< size; i++ ){

html = html + "<option value = " + teamsarray[i] + ">"+teamsarray[i]+"</option>";


    }

html = html +"</select>";
}</script>';
```

basically what I'm trying to do is echo the javascript through php.  I'm trying to make a dropdown with values that I get from php.  Which will be added dynamically with the addrow function.

Comment: Show us the generated markup.

Comment: The default string representation of arrays is `"Array"`, I don't think you want that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass php array to javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-php-array-to-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for json_encode, so you might do something like this:

```
if (empty($teamsarray)) $teamsarray = array();
echo '<input type = "button" id = '.$buttonid.'  value = "Agregar" onclick = "addrow(\'' . $leaguesarray[$numofleagues] . '\','.json_encode($teamsarray).'); return false;" />';
```

Comment: I used json_encode however javascript is still giving me a undefined for the value

Comment: Hmm, well undefined is strange since the code I suggested explicitly defines a value if it is undefined. Can you provide a jsfiddle so we can take a look? If so I could fix it up in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, arrays look like: [2,4,6].  The php implode command can help here.

```
    $buttonid = 42;
    $leaguesarray[$numofleagues] = 66;
    $teamsarray = array(2,4,6);

    $teams = implode(',',$teamsarray);

    $input = <<<EOT
<input type="button" id="$buttonid" value="Agregar" onclick="addrow($leaguesarray[$numofleagues],[$teams])" />
EOT;
    echo $input . "\n";
```

Yields:

```
<input type="button" id="42" value="Agregar" onclick="addrow(66,[2,4,6])" />
```

Which I think is what you want.

EDITED:

@Dustin Grahams suggestion to use json_encode is a good one.  Replace the implode with:

```
$teams = json_encode($teamsarray);
```

And drop the extra brackets from the template.

Comment: thanks for the response.  However I used the json_encode and passed it with the addrow function.  my javascript looks like addrow(something, teams) teams is my array.  However I get undefined.

Comment: Okay so I tried your method I have my teamsarray which contains '5a7' '8' etc.  I then did $teams = implode(',',$teamsarray); and passed it as $teams, however when I get the values the elements inside of the array spell out array.

Comment: As previously requested, post the actual html that you generated.  Your posted code is very confusing and it's difficult to figure out what exactly is going on.