# Javascript Convert PHP Json into a javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, json

In php I used `json_encode(...)` and then got the value in Javascript, looks as the following:

```
["float","float","float","float"]  // PS: This is a string...
```

And I would like to make this into a normal javascript array, like so:

```
Arr[0] // Will be float
Arr[1] // Will be float
Arr[2] // Will be float
Arr[3] // Will be float
```

How is this possible?

Comment: if you passed the array back using json_encode() you have an array and you can index it by the method you showed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP array to a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It sounds like you're retrieving a JSON string in JavaScript (perhaps via AJAX?). If you need to make this into an actual array value, you'd probably want to use `JSON.parse()`.

```
var retrievedJSON = '["float","float","float","float"]'; // normally from AJAX
var myArray = JSON.parse(retrievedJSON);
```

If you're actually writing out a value into the page, rather than using AJAX, then you should be able to simply echo the output of `json_encode` directly, without quoting; JSON itself is valid JavaScript.

```
var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($myPhpArray); ?>;
```

Comment: very nice. I taught it is object in java script.  Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 7):

```
var myArray = <?= json_encode($myPhpArray); ?>;
```

Pretty simple. ;-)

Example:

```
<?php
  $myPhpArray = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myJsArray = <?= json_encode($myPhpArray); ?>;
</script>
```

Should output (view-source):

```
<script type="javascript">
  var myJsArray = ["foo","bar","baz"];
</script>
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7e4605ddf9891877fba49cff3d1e815ea880be8)

Comment: And that gives me the javascript array?

Comment: yes. it's taking an PHP variable and converting in to JSON which javascript will be able to parse and store.

Comment: As an explanation it might be helpful to note that JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a *subset* of the JavaScript language and so can be parsed successfully by any JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: Indeed, JSON!=JavaScript, it's just a serialized representation of data that JavaScript (and many other languages) can translate.

Answer (score 2):

I reccomend using jquery.  The php file should look as such ...

```
//location.php
<?php
$change = array('key1' => $var1, 'key2' => $var2, 'key3' => $var3);
echo json_encode($change);
?>
```

Then the jquery script ...

```
<script>
$.get("location.php", function(data){
var duce = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var art1 = duce.key1;
var art2 = duce.key2;
var art3 = duce.key3;
});
</script>
```