# Get value from remote php server in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have two sites, site A is just html and javascript, and site B has php. What I need is to get variables from site B in site A.

EX:

site A is like

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  //this script has to get the values from siteB
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><!-- here i will do something with the data of site B --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Site b is like:

```
<?php
  var1= "something";
  var2= "somethingElse";
?>
```

I was thinking to use JSON or Ajax but i do not understand exactly how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994858/javascript-convert-php-json-into-a-javascript-array

Comment: Ok, thanks to all of you that had answered. Sorry if it was a duplicate, it seems that I was not able to make myself uderstand by the stack overflow search engine. I manage to do what I need with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "filename.html",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
        // data will contain var1 and var2
   },
   error: function(data) {
        alert("Problem - perhaps malformed JSON?");
   }
  });
});
```

and change your PHP file to be something like:

```
{
   "var1" : "something",
   "var2" : "somethingElse"
}
```

Confirmed to work.
Make sure that your file is a well-formed JSON, otherwise "success" won't be fire.

Note - I am implying usage of JQuery here. Your HTML file should include:

```
<script type="txt/javascript" src="jquery-1.8b1.js"></script>
```

Comment: **remote** server. That will break on the same origin policy. Well, it would if the PHP didn't throw a 500 error. That is a chunk of JSON, not PHP. Oh, it breaks before it gets that far, `$` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

File B

```
<?php

$array[var1] = 'Something';
$array[var2] = 'else';

echo json_encode( $array );
```

File A (jQuery)

```
$.getJSON( $( 'file.php', function( data ) {

    $( 'div' ).html( data.var1 + ' ' + data.var2 );

}
```

---

Edited -- As mentioned, can't do this cross domain without doing some other measures.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript cannot use ajax cross site, for security reasons. The only way to make this happen is to have but one php file on site A that can redirect.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET["url"]); ?>
```

And the javascript can call the url:

```
/redir.php?url=http://siteb.com/valuetoget.php
```

There is no way that I know of to do this with no php on the calling website.

Comment: There are [several ways around the same origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) but an HTTP redirect is not one of them.

Comment: After your edit, the PHP is now performing a proxy not a redirect, it is failing to set a suitable content-type header, and it provides no security so it makes the server an ideal relay for spammers and other malicious users.

Comment: Where is this method not valid? JS calling same site php file or a php file retrieving data from another server?

Comment: True, I guess you would need to implement some sort of security there.