# Parsing json from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a php multidimensional array and i convert it with into JSON with php json_encode function.

Now, after encoding i echo the json like echo 'var javascriptJson = '.$encoded_in_json_array;

How can i get the values of javascriptJson using javascript ? Or else how can i convert my multidim php array into javascript so i can iterate through it or get the values ?

javascriptJson looks like that :

```
var javascriptJson={
  "AMERICA CENTRALA SI DE SUD": {
    "Argentina": {
      "Recomandari pentru toti calatorii: Vaccinari de rutina": {
        "Difterie\/Tetanos\/Pertussis": "background-color: b6c86;",
        "Rujeola\/Rubeola\/Oreion": "background-color: b1ffff;",
        "Varicela": "background-color: ffffff;",
        "Gripa sezoniera": "background-color: ffffff;"
      },
      "Recomandari de vaccinare pentru majoritatea calatorilor": {
        "Hepatita A": "background-color: a6a6a6;",
        "Tifos": "background-color: d9d9d9;"
      },
      "Recomandari  de vaccinare limitate (in functie de expunere)": {
        "Hepatita B": "background-color: 7f7f7f;",
        "Rabia": "background-color: 93d;"
      },
      "Recomandari speciale de preventie": {
        "Malaria": "background-color: 9bbb59;"
      }
    },
    "Belize": {
      "Recomandari pentru toti calatorii: Vaccinari de rutina": {
        "Difterie\/Tetanos\/Pertussis": "background-color: b6c86;",
        "Rujeola\/Rubeola\/Oreion": "background-color: b1ffff;",
        "Varicela": "background-color: ffffff;",
        "Gripa sezoniera": "background-color: ffffff;"
      },
      "Recomandari de vaccinare pentru majoritatea calatorilor": {
        "Hepatita A": "background-color: a6a6a6;",
        "Tifos": "background-color: d9d9d9;"
      },
      "Recomandari  de vaccinare limitate (in functie de expunere)": {
        "Hepatita B": "background-color: 7f7f7f;",
        "Rabia": "background-color: 93d;"
      },
      "Recomandari speciale de preventie": {
        "Malaria": "background-color: 9bbb59;"
      }
    },
    "Bolivia": {
      "Recomandari pentru toti calatorii: Vaccinari de rutina": {
        "Difterie\/Tetanos\/Pertussis": "background-color: b6c86;",
        "Rujeola\/Rubeola\/Oreion": "background-color: b1ffff;",
        "Varicela": "background-color: ffffff;",
        "Gripa sezoniera": "background-color: ffffff;"
      },
      "Recomandari de vaccinare pentru majoritatea calatorilor": {
        "Hepatita A": "background-color: a6a6a6;",
        "Tifos": "background-color: d9d9d9;"
      },
      "Recomandari  de vaccinare limitate (in functie de expunere)": {
        "Hepatita B": "background-color: 7f7f7f;",
        "Rabia": "background-color: 93d;"
      },
      "Recomandari speciale de preventie": {
        "Malaria": "background-color: 9bbb59;"
      }
    }, .....etc...etc
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you with the problem : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994858/javascript-convert-php-json-into-a-javascript-array

Comment: By using `javascriptJson["AMERICA CENTRALA SI DE SUD"]["Belize"]["Recomandari speciale de preventie"]["Malaria"]`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo he needs an automatic way to do this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i in javascriptJson) {
  console.log(javascriptJson[i]);
  for (var j in javascriptJson[i]) {
     console.log(javascriptJson[i]);
     console.log(javascriptJson[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Recursion should do the job better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop over an object you can do

```
foreach(prop in obj){ 
console.log(prop); // would get you the property name
console.log(obj[prop]); // would get you the value of that property
}
```

That could get you started in this instance.

Comment: the second console statement is an example of the value, this will return the next object down in some cases

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of things you should have a javascript object available after the `var javascriptJson = '.$encoded_in_json_array;` line.

You can iterate over this object using something like:

```
for(region in javascriptJson){
    var region_object = javascriptJson[region];
    // Code to handle each region
    // If you want to look at each country in a region...
    for(country in region_object){
        var country_object = region_object[country];
        // Code to handle each country object
        // You can get values like:
        // country_object['Recomandari pentru toti calatorii: Vaccinari de rutina']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your question**

> How can i get the values of javascriptJson using javascript ? Or else how can i convert my multidim php array into javascript so i can iterate through it or get the values ?

**The solution**

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(/*json-string*/)
```

Now you can iterate through the values like this:

```
for (var property in myObject) {
  // Do whatever you want
}
```