# How to Pass a PHP array to JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

First of all, this question looks a duplicate of [Pass a PHP array to a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function), but I actually used the first solution of [Pass a PHP array to a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function) - and it doesnt seem to work:

More specifically, the php echo line in the code below seems to create erroneous js output according to console error message( Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <); the console shows created html starting with `"var s1 = <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1'..."`

...while I'd expect a clean `var s1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` - the result I also see when I tested the echo line in ideone.com

Any idea why the echo line is creating this stuff, and how to fix this?

Related joomla php code:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

//add jqplot libraries
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

JHTML::script(JUri::root() .'media/system/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js');
//$document->addStyleSheet(JUri::root() .'media/system/js/jquery.jqplot.min.css');
JHtml::stylesheet( JUri::root() . 'media/system/js/jquery.jqplot.min.css' );
JHTML::script(JUri::root() .'media/system/js/jquery.jqplot.min.css');
JHTML::script(JUri::root() .'media/system/js/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js');
JHTML::script(JUri::root() .'media/system/js/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js');
JHTML::script(JUri::root() .'media/system/js/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js');
JHTML::script(JUri::root() .'media/system/js/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.js');
JHTML::script(JUri::root() .'media/system/js/weqlib.js');

$chartvals = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
?>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var s1 = <?php echo json_encode(chartvals); ?>; //!the echo seems to create erroneous js output accoding to console(?)

        plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [s1]); //copied from example at 


    }); //$(document).ready
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `$` to referrence the `chartvals` var at the `json_encode()` function call:

```
var s1 = <?php echo json_encode(chartvals); ?>;
```

Should be

```
var s1 = <?php echo json_encode($chartvals); ?>;
```

To not trap into this sort of mistakes again you can add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your script and set `display_errors` to `on` in your PHP config during development.

Comment: thxn (!) very sloppy mistake of me;-( . very useful error reporting tips (!)

Answer (score 1):

```
var s1 = <?php echo json_encode($chartvals); ?>; //!the echo seems to create
```