# Pass PHP array values to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get the values of PHP Array in JavaScript variable.
Here is my code:

```
    $qry="select * from optin";
    $rlt1=mysql_query($qry);
    $em_ary=array();
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($rlt1)){
        $em_ary=$row;
        echo $em_ary['timer'];}// this echo show all records that I have in data base and I want to get all the values in Javascript


<script>
    var tmr=[];
    tmr='<?php echo json_encode($em_ary['timer']); ?>';
    alert(tmr);// this alert only shows the last record in the database 
<?script>
```

Where I am going wrong or is there any other way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$em_ary[]=$row;` to append

Comment: directly use $row['timer'] $row is already an array

Comment: If I had a penny for each time someone asked how to pass a PHP variable’s value to JavaScript, I’d be a millionaire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP array to a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function)

Comment: wow. but starter will always get struggle them. teach them with smile.

Comment: here there is a problem with code not in passing

Comment: Also, don't use `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated and will be **removed** in a future version of PHP, at which point your code **won't work**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update this line:

```
$em_ary = $row;
```

and change it to:

```
$em_ary[] = $row;
```

You are overwriting the array each time you want to add a new element to it.

Then, in the JS part, update this line:

```
tmr = '<?php echo json_encode($em_ary['timer']); ?>';
```

to:

```
tmr = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($em_ary); ?>');
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion was useful. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting values within your `$em_ary` array in order to make an array of values you need to place `[]` after `$em_ary` which will result you an array

```
$em_ary[]=$row;
```

You need to update this also from

```
tmr='<?php echo json_encode($em_ary['timer']); ?>';
```

into

```
tmr="<?php echo json_encode({$em_ary['timer']}); ?>";
```

Comment: still i am not getting values in javascript variable!