# Calling a JavaScript function inside PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

[While you can pass a PHP array to a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function), can you pass the opposite? (a JavaScript function into an PHP array).

Consider this code. I want to call a JavaScript timer inside a PHP array, as the array later randomizes messages for an echo.

```
$messages = array('How are you today?', 'Perfect day for flying, isnt it?', 'You have flown last on '.$lastflown.'.', 'The time is /* insert the JavaScript function to call a timer here */');
$key = array_rand($messages);
```

And of course I want to display the message:

```
<?php echo $messages[$key]; ?>
```

Is this possible? If not, how can this be bypassed? Perhaps a JavaScript randomizer instead?

Comment: *"Perhaps a JavaScript randomizer instead?"* yes I highly recommend to read http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/218196 to get a better understanding of how PHP and JavaScript interrelate.

Comment: No you can't, like Felix say, php is server side. And the javascript is executed on browser, not on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code help you.

```
$messages = array('How are you today?', 'Perfect day for flying, isnt it?', 'You have flown last on '.$lastflown.'.', 'The time is <script> document.write(new Date().toString());</script>');
$key = array_rand($messages);

<?php echo $messages[$key]; ?>
```

You need surround your JavaScript code with  tags. To show  JavaScript output use document.write() function.

This string `'The time is <script> document.write(new Date().toString());</script>'` will be show like `The time is Wed Oct 21 2015 17:18:32 GMT+0300 (MSK)` in browser.