# How do I pass a PHP array to a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following JavaScript that sends parameters to a PHP file:

```
function getOutput()
{
$.ajax({
url:'myPHPFile.php',
data:{APIKey:$APIKey,Password:$APIPass,Alias:$Alias,DataCenter:$DataCenter},
type:'POST',
complete: function (response) {
$('#output').html(response.responseText);
},
error: function ()
{
$('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
}
});
return response.responseText;
}`
```

Which changes the following HTML to the output of the PHP file:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return getOutput();"> test </a>
```

Here is the PHP

```
<?php
//  echo nl2br("\nIntializing api.php \n");
// DATA SECTION
$APIKey = $_POST["APIKey"];
$APIPass = $_POST["Password"];
$AccountAlias = $_POST["Alias"];
$dataCenter = $_POST["DataCenter"];

$data = array(
  "APIKey" => $APIKey,
  "Password" => $APIPass,   
);

$url_send = 'https://api.ctl.io/REST/Auth/Logon/';
$json_data = json_encode($data);

function sendPostData($url, $post, $cook = null){
//  echo "Beginning sendPostData($url, $post, $cook)";

$ch = curl_init($url);
$headers= array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

if (!empty($cook))
  {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json','Cookie:'.$cook));     
  }

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
return $result; 
};
$myresult = sendPostData($url_send, $json_data);
//  print_r ($myresult);
$decodedresult = json_decode($myresult);
// print_r ($decodedresult);
'/reply-(.*?)-private/';
preg_match_all('/Tier3(.*?)path=/', $myresult, $matches); 
$cookies = array(); 

foreach($matches[0] as $item) 
        { 
          parse_str($item, $cookie); 
          $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie); 
        }
$prefix = 'Tier3.API.Cookie=';
$cookie = implode(" ",$matches[0]);

// Call the customer server list
$data = array(
  'AccountAlias' => $AccountAlias,
  'Location' => $dataCenter
);
$data_url =     'https://api.ctl.io/REST/Server/GetAllServersForAccountHierarchy/';
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$dataResult = sendPostData($data_url,$data_string, $cookie);
print_r($dataResult);
return $dataResult;
```

`

How can I get the $dataResult PHP array into a javascript variable so I can parse it? It is a big JSON response from an API.

Thanks.

Comment: either send the json as the ajax response, or embed it in the page when you generate the page: `var somevar = <?php json_encode($your_array); ?>;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP array to a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are (normally) asynchronous, this means that the `return response.responseText;` will be executed immediately and should even raise an error related to `response` being undefined.

You'll have the response in the `complete` event of the ajax call and is inside there where you should go on with the execution of the script. jQuery will parse the JSON automatically and `response` will be the resulting object.

At the other side, the PHP script should just print the result of `json_encode()` *and nothing else* in order for the response to be valid JSON.