# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal with JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

So I have...

```
 var newfavz = 'Array (


[0] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]
[1] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]
[2] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]

)
';
```

on my console.log, but somehow there is a syntax error: unterminated string literal. I've looked around and tried methods such as str_replace "/" with "//" or a regex like .replace(/^/+/g, ''); because it seems like JavaScript don't allow strings to be broken into multiple lines or something like that.

This all started with an SQL query like so...

```
$favurl = [];
$favquery = "SELECT * FROM userfavs WHERE users = '$username'";
$favresult = mysqli_query($conn, $favquery);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($favresult)) {

array_push($favurl, $row['fav_id']);
```

Afterwards, I did

```
var newfavz = <?php print_r ($favurl); ?>
```

which led to the above.

Is there any way I could use to solve the syntax error? Thanks!

Comment: `echo` result of `json_encode` instead of using `print_r`. The printed string is useless in JavaScript environment, Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: ah sorry I was using print_r when I was doing the debugging :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause multiline strings are not allowed in js:

```
"A
 B"
```

Is a syntax error. You might remove all newlines and replace them with \n, or you use template literals:

```
`A
 B`
```

In your code:

```
var newfavz =` <?php print_r ($favurl); ?>`;
```

So much about the error. However the string is still unusable, it needs to be parsed. Have a look at JSON or write your own little parser.

Comment: To add to this, on the server you should encode the array to a json object using json_encode() method before passing to JS.

Comment: Hey, I forgot to add this to the question, but I did use a JSON_encode method before I inserted the data into the SQL database. So far, the only way I've found to remove this unterminated string literal error is to do another JSON_encode which is pretty silly IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Either use ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var newfavz = `Array (


[0] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]
[1] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]
[2] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]

)
`;
```

Or with a backslash:

```
var newfavz = 'Array (\n\
\n\
\n\
[0] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\n\
[1] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\n\
[2] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\n\
\n\
)\
';
```

Or concatenate:

```
var newfavz = 'Array (\n' +
  '\n' +
  '\n' +
  '[0] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\n' +
  '[1] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\n' +
  '[2] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\n' +
  '\n' +
  ')\n';
```

`\n` is used to represent a `newline`.

Comment: Thanks man! I used the `` characters and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You must put a backslash at the end of each line to have a multiline string:

```
var newfavz = 'Array (\
[0] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\
[1] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\
[2] => [" 6 "," 1 "," 2 "," 5 "," 3 "," 4 "]\
)\
';
```