# getting js array from php array using ajax, without concatenation

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) - without success

```
function abc() {
    var sky = 'blue';
    var earth = 'deep';
    var sun = 'gold';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'images.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'earth': earth, 'sun': sun, 'sky': sky},
        success: function(data) {
            // here I want new values as js array from php array
        }
    });
}
```

**images.php**

```
... some code...
$sky = "over";
$earth = "down";
$sun = "middle";

echo array($sky, $earth, $sun);
```

The above is very simplified example. In reality my variables inside php array are much more complex. So I don't want use the concatenation method on php side and `split` a string on `js` side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: @iainn, already said - tried on that link - there is no such example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to send data back to your JS Code.

Your JS side :

```
function abc() {
    var sky = 'blue';
    var earth = 'deep';
    var sun = 'gold';
    $.post('images.php', {'earth': earth, 'sun': sun, 'sky': sky}).done(
        function(json) {
            data = JSON.parse(json);
            //use data
        }
    });
}
```

images.php:

```
$sky = "over";
$earth = "down";
$sun = "middle";

echo json_encode(array($sky, $earth, $sun));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Just - is it possible to write the same following the structure of `ajax - success` function ?

Comment: yes you can, that's the traditional way of handling the jquery success callback, but since the implementation of $.Deferreds and more sophisticated callbacks,  done is the preferred way to implement success callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

please use JSON to handle communication between PHP and JS.
PHP should be doing:

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

and Jquery should be working with http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ most probably