# How I can pass array value of PHP into Ajax jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, mariadb

I get statusText: OK value, but I cannot get PHP object or array values.
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/1-HWWEJKvSbCYKUkoGHytA

I have Fedora 30 with 2.4.39 HTTPd, PHP 7.6, MySQL: 10.3.12.
I'm using latest jQuery.
I set it into my PHP file:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'get.php',
  type: 'post',
  })
  .done(function(a) {
    $("#workSpace").html(a); 
    alert(a)
    $.each(a, function( key, value ) {
      $("#workSpace").html(key + ": " + value);
    });
   })
   .fail(function(a) {
        $("#workSpace").html(a); 
   })
   .always(function(a) {
        var example = Object.keys(a)

        $.each(example, function( key, value ) {
       $("#workSpace").html(key + ": " + value);
    });
    });
});
```

I expected work with objects or array passed by PHP like this.

```
{id:1, name: hola, description: That's an example}
{id:2, name: hello, description: That's nice}
{id:3, name: welcome, description: That's so way}
```

However, I just only get `statusText: OK`

Comment: You need to show us how your php is sending the json to the client.

Comment: Probably a dupe also... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function ?

Answer (score 0):

you will not have many responses from your PHP in one request made, try to collect all the data received from your db in a variable. Modify your php code as follows.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','example','tasks');
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM task")->fetch_array();
$array = array();
while ($getResults = $stmt->fetch_array())
{
    $array[] = $getResults;
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($getResults);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($getResults);
```

Regards

Comment: Need to `json_encode($array)` also remove `->fetch_array()` from the query.

Comment: I've tried this but It does not work. I still get statusText:OK

Answer (score 0):

have you try something like this :

```
$array = array();
while ($getResults = $stmt->fetch_array())
{
    $array[] = $getResults;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

and adding the content type on the $.ajax request :

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'get.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json"
  })
          .done(function (a) {

            $("#workSpace").html(a);
            alert(a)
            $.each(a, function (key, value) {
              $("#workSpace").html(key + ": " + value);
            });
          })
          .fail(function (a) {
            $("#workSpace").html(a);
          })
          .always(function (a) {
            var example = Object.keys(a)

            $.each(example, function (key, value) {
              $("#workSpace").html(key + ": " + value);
            });
          });
```

Comment: Probably want to mention remove `->fetch_array()` from the query.

Comment: I've tried this but It does not work. I still get statusText:OK

Comment: sure dataType? add contentType: 'application/json', on your $.ajax below dataType