# Laravel collection to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Why laravel collection can use directly as a javascript variable but not a php array or object?

In **testing.blade.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
$testingArray = [1,2,3];
$testingObject = new stdClass();
$testingObject->testing = "Testing";
$testingObject->hello = "Hello";
$testingObject->bye = "Bye";
$testingCollection = Collection::make($testingArray);
?>

<script>
        var myArray = {!! $testingArray !!}; //Not work 
        var myObject = {!! $testingObject !!}; //Not work 

        var myArray = {!! json_encode($testingArray) !!}; //Work
        var myObject = {!! json_encode($testingObject) !!}; //Work
        var myCollection = {!! $testingCollection !!}; //Work
</script>
```

Any references?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4885796/2075158

Comment: What happens between `{!! .. !!}` is *output*. PHP has no way of printing arrays and objects, because it hasn't got any instructions on how to turn them into a string. The Laravel Collection object probably has `__toString` implemented that allows the conversion.

Comment: And [here it is](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method___toString), which points towards [this trait it's using](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php#L878).

Comment: Don't forget the `@json` directive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Collection` objects are automatically serialised to JSON when you convert them to a string.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json says

> models and collections are converted to JSON when cast to a string

This code you showed:

```
{!! $testingCollection !!}
```

tries to output `$testingCollection` to the view. Doing that obviously requires it to be turned into a string. This will automatically trigger its JSON serialisation, as per the documentation.

This happens via its standard `__toString()` function, which then points to a trait which calls `toJSON()` to perform the serialisation.

That in turn means that JavaScript can immediately read it, because as you're probably aware, valid JSON can be used as a JavaScript object literal (since JSON syntax is a subset of JS object syntax).