# For each loop with JavaScript and PHP generating markers in LeafLet

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I am trying to loop through my SQL result with PHP and JavaScript to set markers on a LeafLet Map. The Data contains the name, latitude, longitude and number.

Here is my code:

```
var ticker = <?php echo mysqli_num_rows($result); ?>;
for ( let i = 0; i < ticker; i++) {
  var latitude = <?php echo json_encode($row["latitude"]); ?>;
  var longitude = <?php echo json_encode($row["longitude"]); ?>;
  var marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);
  var popup = <?php echo json_encode($row["name"] . " " . $row["number"]); ?>;
  marker.bindPopup(popup);
}
```

It should add two markers, but somehow it only generates one marker with the data from the first entry.

Comment: It looks like it would create two markers on rhe same spot. You don't seem to be looping over $row. Instead of mixing php and js like this it would probably make a lot more sense to have php output the necessary data into a json array, pass that to JS, decode it and loop over that.

Comment: i tried that, but i cant make it work. extracting the data from my json object always says its undefined

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($values); ?>));
        console.log(Object.values(data));
            for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data.Name);
           }

Comment: Why would you call JSON.stringify on a value that already is JSON, only to then parse it again? You _just_ need to output the `json_encode` result - one of the main points of JSON is that it can be parsed as valid JavaScript code already, without needing any extra steps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4885796/1427878

Comment: yip, thats true :D dunno what i thought there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a solution. Thanks for any help!

PHP

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$values = [];
while($value = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $values[] = $value;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($values); ?>;

for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i][0];
    var lat = data[i][1];
    var lon = data[i][2];
    var ums = data[i][3];
    var popup = name + ums;
    var marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup(popup);
}
```